# "Upper derivative" of indefinite integral of upper semicontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, semicontinuous-functions

The following problem is stated as [Exercise 22.A(iii)](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA169) in the book Van Rooij, Schikhof: *A Second Course on Real Functions*.

> Let $f\colon [a,b]\to{\mathbb R}$ be Lebesgue integrable and upper semicontinuous. If $v$ is an indefinite integral of $f$, then $D^+v \le f$.

This serves an auxiliary result used a few times when defining and proving some basic properties of [Perron integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_integral). The same result can be found as [Theorem 5.32](https://books.google.com/books?id=VN8RCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA85) in Gordon: *The integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock*.

Here indefinite integral means that $v(y)-v(x) = \int_x^y f(t) \; \mathrm{d}t$ for each $x,y\in[a,b]$ and $D^+v$ is defined as
$$D^+v(x) = \limsup_{y\to x} \frac{v(y)-v(x)}{y-x}.$$
This quantity is related to [Dini derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative), with the difference the the limit superior is not one-sided. (Some texts use the notation $\overline Dv$ instead of $D^+v$, but I used here notation from the text where I saw this problem.)

How can we show the above result?

I'll be grateful for comments on my approach posted below as an answer and also for other possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $v$ is indefinite integral of $f$, we have $$v(y)-v(x) = \int_x^y f(t) \; \mathrm{d}t$$
for any $x,y\in[a,b]$.

We have
\begin{align*}
D^+ v(x)
&= \limsup_{y\to x} \frac{v(y)-v(x)}{y-x} \\
&= \limsup_{y\to x} \frac{\int_x^y f(t) \; \mathrm{d}t}{y-x}. \\
\end{align*}
From upper semicontinuity we know that for any given $x$ and $\varepsilon>0$ we have $f(y)<f(x)+\varepsilon$ for all $y$'s that are close enough to $x$. So for such $y$'s we get
$$\int_x^y f(t) \; \mathrm{d}t \le (f(x)+\varepsilon)(y-x)$$
and
$$D^+ v(x) \le f(x)+\varepsilon.$$
Since this is true for every $\varepsilon>0$, we finally get $D^+ v(x) \le f(x).$

Comment: Maybe it's a bit late for comments, but your proof convinces me, at least.