# Riemann integral using piecewise linear and $C^1$-functions as upper functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup$The following is [Exercise 22.C](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA172) from Van Rooij, Schikhof: *A Second Course on Real Functions*.

> For any class $\mathcal F$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ one can define $\mathcal F$-integrability by calling a function $f\colon{[a,b]}\to{\mathbb R}$
>   *$\mathcal F$-integrable* if for every $\varepsilon>0$ $f$ has upper and lower functions $u,v\in\mathcal F$ such that
>   $$\newcommand{\rozd}[3]{\left[{#3}\right]_{#1}^{#2}}\rozd abu \le \rozd abv + \varepsilon.$$
>   The class of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$ gives us the Perron integral, the class of all absolutely continuous functions defines the Lebesgue integral.
>
> Prove now that each of the following classes of functions leads to the Riemann integral: the class of all piecewise linear continuous functions; the class of all functions that have continuous derivatives.

In the above, $\rozd xyu$ denotes $u(y)-u(x)$. By lower and upper function we mean $D^+v \le f \le D^-u$, where $D^+v$ and $D^+u$ denotes the lower and upper derivative, i.e.,
$$D^+v(x) = \limsup_{y\to x} \frac{v(y)-v(x)}{y-x} \qquad D^-u(x) = \liminf_{y\to x} \frac{u(y)-u(x)}{y-x}.$$
Some text calls this minor and major function. (For example, Gordon: *The integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock.*)

The intention of this exercise is to show that similar construction which can lead to [Perron integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_integral) and Lebesgue integral. I'll be grateful for comments on my attempt posted as an answer and also for alternative solutions. And also for some references where this can be found.$\endgroup$

Answer (score 0):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup$Suppose that  we have $$g\le f \le h,$$ where $g$ is upper semicontinuous and $h$ is lower semicontinuous and both $g$, $h$ are Lebesgue integrable.
If we put
$$v(x) = \int_a^x g(s) \;\mathrm{d} s, \qquad u(x) = \int_a^x h(s) \;\mathrm{d} s$$
then from [Exercise 22.A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537460/upper-derivative-of-indefinite-integral-of-upper-semicontinuous-function) we have $D^+ v\le g$ and $D^-u \ge h$, hence
$$D^+v \le f \le D^-u.$$

On the other hand, if $D^+v$ and $D^-u$ are Riemann integrable, then we know from [Theorem 15.3](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA95) that
$$v(x) = \int_a^x D^+v(s) \;\mathrm{d} s, \qquad u(x) = \int_a^x D^-u(s) \;\mathrm{d} s.$$

In fact, here we will be using very simple functions in place of $g$, $h$, $u$, $v$; so the above can be checked for these functions using direct computation. But since we already know more general results, I have simply mentioned them instead of including the computations.

The basic idea is to use a correspondence between:

- piecewise linear upper functions of $f$ and step functions which are above $f$;
- continuously differentiable upper functions of $f$ and continuous functions which are above $f$.

---

*$\mathcal F$-integrable function is Riemann integrable.* Notice that in both cases we have that $D^+v$ and $D^-u$ are Riemann integrable. (In fact, they are continuous with the exception of at most finitely many points.) So we have
$$\newcommand{\rozd}[3]{\left[{#3}\right]_{#1}^{#2}}\rozd abv = \int_a^b D^+v \le \underline{\int_a^b} f(t) \;\mathrm{d} t \le \overline{\int_a^b} f(t) \;\mathrm{d} t \le  \int_a^b D^-u = \rozd abu.$$
(Here $\underline\int$ and $\overline\int$ denotes lower and upper Riemann integral.)

From the fact that $\sup\{\rozd abv\}=\inf\{\rozd abu\}$ (where supremum and infimum are taken only over lower and upper functions from $\mathcal F$, respectively) we get that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

---

*Riemann-integrable function is $\mathcal F$-integrable.*  If a function is Riemann integrable, we can approximate it from below and from above by step functions $g$ and $h$ in such way that $g\le f\le h$ and the function $g$ and $y$ can be made arbitrarily close in the sense
$$\int_a^b (h(t)-g(t)) \;\mathrm{d} t<\varepsilon.$$
Notice that we can arbitrarily change values in the points belonging to partition, since we assume that $h(t) \ge \sup\limits_{t\in[a_i,a_{i+1}]} f(t)$ on each interval from the partition (and similarly for $g$). So we can also assume that $g$ and $h$ are upper and lower semicontinuous, respectively.
Therefore we get $$D^+v \le g \le f \le h \le D^-u$$
for $v$ and $u$ defined as above. Moreover, $v$ and $u$ are piecewise linear and we have
$$\int_a^b g(t) \;\mathrm{d} t=\rozd abv \qquad \int_a^b h(t) \;\mathrm{d} t=\rozd abu.$$
So in this way we get the $f$ is $\mathcal F$-integrable if $\mathcal F$ is the class of piecewise linear functions.

For $C^1$-functions basically the same argument works, but we need to show that Riemann integrable function $f$ can be approximated by continuous functions $h$ and $g$. To achieve this we simply modify the step functions by adding small enough triangles. In this way we get $g$ and $h$ which are piecewise linear continuous functions and their indefinite integrals $u$ and $v$ are $C^1$.

*Remark.* We could get in a similar way $C^\infty$-functions. Instead of a small triangle we would use some kind of [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).$\endgroup$